# How to use Chrome TTS (Text to Speech) on Android webview app?

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm using TTS (text to speech) on my web project. And now I want to use this project in webview as a mobile application. When I click "Listen" button, my javascript for TTS is okay for mobile and desktop browsers. But in Android webview, there is no sound when I click "Listen" button.

I add javascriptInterface but result didn't change. Is there any idea, can I use TTS on android webview or not? Or is there any other important thing for to do?

Comment: I have the same issue